# Where is the Authorization token (delivered via an HTTP header) stored?

Tags: http, authorization

When I investigate HTTP requests, I notice that some of them use the `"Authorization": "Bearer" + token` header, in contrast to the popular cookie that is used so that the server can identify its clients. I was wondering where such Authorization tokens are stored? Are they stored as a file, or in the same way that cookies are stored?

Furthermore, am I able to retrieve these tokens from a browser (eg. via Inspect Element)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These can be stored in the browser local storage or session storage. And then your JS code needs to pick them up and set them in the headers.

See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19867599/what-is-the-difference-between-localstorage-sessionstorage-session-and-cookies for details on  the differences between them.

Storage (either of them) vs cookies - Cookies are automatically sent by the browser whereas storage is very generic and you can store anything in there, so if the webapp stores auth related stuff it needs to send it back via code.

Comment: Thank you!
Does that mean it is not possible that an HTTP request (eg. normal browser GET request) that is not an xhr request generated by JavaScript cannot contain such a header?

Answer (score 2):

I store this token at browser storage like this.

```
localStorage.setItem('access_token',JSON.stringify(tokenParameter))
```

When you need to use this access token just simply collect this  like this way

```
var access_token = localStorage.getItem('access_token');
```

How to use with Bearer ?

```
'Bearer '+access_token or 'Bearer '+localStorage.getItem('access_token');
```